# Suppose that each one has $k, 2k,...,nk$ objects and in each step we distribute others some of them.

Tags: combinatorics

Suppose that we are n and each one has $k, 2k,...,nk$ objects and in each step we distribute other some of them equally. After how many steps at least we have equal objects in each one?

Comment: I understand there are $n$ people, where person $i$ has has $ni$ objects for $i=1,2,...,n$. Can you clarify what the “distribute other some of them equally” part means?

Comment: in each step person i distribute some objects to other n-1 people equally from his hand. between 0< j < ni (but equally to each one)

Comment: why it is very nice question.

Comment: it is nice and interesting question if u r good u can give answer but i think so your butt is not enough...

Comment: @CenapOzel It was hard to understand what you were asking, so people downvoted and closed it. However, I think I just figured it out, and it is a very nice problem. I posted a solution if you are interested.

Comment: thanks dear Mike u r very nice and good..

Answer (score 1):

> - If $k$ is a multiple of $n$, then it is possible to equalize, and the fastest way to do it takes $n-1$ steps.
> - Otherwise it is impossible to equalize.

When $k$ is a multiple of $n$, the optimal algorithm is this:

- The person with $2k$ objects gives everyone $k/n$ objects.
- The person who originally had $3k$ objects gives everyone $2k/n$ objects.
- $\vdots$
- The person who originally had $nk$ objects gives everyone $(n-1)\cdot k/n$ objects.

To see this is optimal, suppose there were only $n-2$ steps. There would exist two people $x$ and $y$ who never gave any objects away. Since $x$ and $y$ started unequal, and they always receive the same amount of objects, they will be unequal at the end.

On the other hand, suppose $k$ is not a multiple of $n$. Consider the number of objects each person has $\pmod n$. Initially, the person with $k$ objects has a number which is $\not\equiv 0\pmod n$, while the person with $kn$ objects has a number which is $\equiv 0\pmod n$. This property will be preserved after each step. Indeed, if someone gives $x$ objects to everyone else, then most people's value increases by $x\pmod n$, while one persons value increases by
$$
-(n-1)x\equiv x-nx\equiv x-0\equiv x\pmod n
$$
Since everyone's number increases by the same amount $\pmod n$, the person who initially had $k$ and the person who initially had $kn$ will always have different values $\pmod n$, which means their values can never be equal.

Comment: suppose that we are 5 and  each one has 10 20 30 40 50 oplease consider it

Comment: i explain  that some of the objects in your hand  and   i ask u at least how many steps...

Comment: many thanks dear Mike Earnest